# How to connect metamask in another computerA(windows) to a private hyperledger besu in another computerB(ubuntu)

Tags: metamask, besu

I have here a private hyperledger besu network running on my computerB(ubuntu). I wanna know how can I connect the metamask wallet on my computerA(windows) to the network in my computerB. I tried networking them and adding the network in the metamask my rpc url: http://(computerB ipaddress):(the port of the node running). But it says cannot fetch chain ID. I can ping both computers, but why is this error showing?

Answer (score 0):

Probably is not a Metamask problem, but a network problem. Do you have access to this specific port? You can check:

[https://kb.synology.com/en-me/DSM/tutorial/Whether_TCP_port_is_open_or_closed#:~:text=Press%20the%20Windows%20key%20%2B%20R,only%20a%20cursor%20will%20show](https://kb.synology.com/en-me/DSM/tutorial/Whether_TCP_port_is_open_or_closed#:%7E:text=Press%20the%20Windows%20key%20%2B%20R,only%20a%20cursor%20will%20show).